# r - copy value based on match in another column

Tags: r

In this data frame:

```
Item <- c("A","B","A","A","A","A","A","B")
Trial <- c("Fam","Fam","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test")
Condition <-c("apple","cherry","Trash","Trash","Trash","Trash","Trash","Trash")
ID <- c(rep("01",8))


df <- data.frame(cbind(Item,Trial,Condition,ID))
```

I would like to replace the "Trash" value of `df$condition` at `df$Trial == "Test"`. The new value of `df$condition` should be a copy `df$condition` at `df$Trial == "Fam"`, based on a match of Fam and Test Trials in  `df$Item`.

So my final data frame should look like this

```
  Item Trial Condition ID
1    A   Fam     apple 01
2    B   Fam    cherry 01
3    A  Test     apple 01
4    A  Test     apple 01
5    A  Test     apple 01
6    A  Test     apple 01
7    A  Test     apple 01
8    B  Test    cherry 01
```

Ultimately I would like to do this for unique ID's in my original data frame. So I guess I will have to apply the function within `ddply` or so later on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do a self *binary join* on `df` when `Trial != "Test"` and update the `Condition` column *by reference* using the `data.table` package, for instance

```
library(data.table) ## V 1.9.6+
setDT(df)[df[Trial != "Test"], Condition := i.Condition, on = c("Item", "ID")]
df
#    Item Trial Condition ID
# 1:    A   Fam     apple 01
# 2:    B   Fam    cherry 01
# 3:    A  Test     apple 01
# 4:    A  Test     apple 01
# 5:    A  Test     apple 01
# 6:    A  Test     apple 01
# 7:    A  Test     apple 01
# 8:    B  Test    cherry 01
```

Or (with some modification of @docendos) suggestion, simply

```
setDT(df)[, Condition := Condition[Trial != "Test"], by = .(Item, ID)]
```

Comment: I get an error when I run this: Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(dataAll), dataAll[Trial != "Test"], `:=`(condition,  : 
  unused argument (on = c("Item", "ppcode")). Now ID == ppcode, which has several levels referring to different people. I get the same error when only running  Also I can't get my R Studio to update data.table to Version 1.9.6, I only get to 1.9.4,

Comment: This is why I wrote `V 1.9.6+`. Please update to the newest `data.table` version on Cran.

Comment: Can you help me update via CRAN? When I click on update packages in R studio, the data.table package is not enlisted.

Comment: Run `install.packages("data.table")` and the reload it using `library(data.table)`

Comment: that does not solve it. I always stay with version 1.9.4. Maybe because I am at work and some firewall thingy prevents the most recent version to be loaded....

Comment: Does this works for you instead `setDT(df)[, Condition := Condition[Trial != "Test"], by = .(Item, ID)]`? (Credit to @docendo)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(df) %>% 
    filter(Trial=='Fam') %>% 
    left_join(df, ., by = c('Item', 'ID')) %>% 
    mutate(Condition = ifelse(Condition.x=='Trash',
            as.character(Condition.y), as.character(Condition.x))) %>% 
    select(c(1,2,4,7))
```

Or as suggested by @docendodiscimus

```
df %>% 
    group_by(ID, Item) %>%
    mutate(Condition = Condition[Condition != "Trash"])
```

Comment: For the given example, this should also work: `df %>% group_by(ID, Item) %>% mutate(Condition = Condition[Condition != "Trash"])`

Comment: @docendodiscimus you should probably post it while adding `setDT(df)[, Condition := Condition[Trial != "Test"], by = .(Item, ID)]` too

Comment: @DavidArenburg, no need for another answer here. Either akrun or you can add that to your answers

Answer (score 2):

You could also just create a for-loop and loop through all the values that need to be changed. This setup makes it easy to add other items and/or change the type of condition later on.

```
> for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
>     
>     if(df[i, 1] == "A") {
>         df2[i, 3] <- "apple"
>     }
>     else if(df[i, 1] == "B") {
>         df2[i, 3] <- "cherry"
>     }
> }
```

Comment: Nice one, but I'd rather have a generic col name instead, looping through all possible values is rather cumbersome in my case

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question then ;). Kind of wasted my time here haha.

Comment: Lesson learned for next time! Thank you still for your help with this.