# Copy values to rows based on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataset that I am trying to copy an index date variable for controls based on their matched case's index date. In this data, case = 1, control = 0. Each pair has a unique ID in the "matchid" column and time = the timepoint. I have the below sample dataset:

```
  Study_ID  time index_date  case matchid
   <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 101        0          2     1     1
 2 101        1          2     1     1
 3 101        2          2     1     1
 4 101        3          2     1     1
 5 340        0          NA    0     1
 6 340        1          NA    0     1
 7 340        2          NA    0     1
 8 340        3          NA    0     1
```

I need the index_date column for rows 5-8 to be "2" based on "matchid" being the same so it would look like the below:

```
  Study_ID  time index_date  case matchid
   <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 101        0          2     1     1
 2 101        1          2     1     1
 3 101        2          2     1     1
 4 101        3          2     1     1
 5 340        0          2     0     1
 6 340        1          2     0     1
 7 340        2          2     0     1
 8 340        3          2     0     1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as the solution for a similar question did not resolve my issue.

I have tried the below Stack Overflow solutions but I am getting errors.

[Copy values from one row to another based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67399813/copy-values-from-one-row-to-another-based-on-condition?newreg=c75a97bbb15f47fb87f7df5a19348948)

[r - copy value based on match in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998856/r-copy-value-based-on-match-in-another-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```r
library(dplyr)
quux %>%
  mutate(
    index_date = if_else(is.na(index_date), na.omit(index_date)[1], index_date),
    .by = c(matchid, time)
  )
#   Study_ID time index_date case matchid
# 1      101    0          2    1       1
# 2      101    1          2    1       1
# 3      101    2          2    1       1
# 4      101    3          2    1       1
# 5      340    0          2    0       1
# 6      340    1          2    0       1
# 7      340    2          2    0       1
# 8      340    3          2    0       1
```

(Note: `.by=` needs dplyr_1.1 or newer; if you have older, pre-use `group_by(matchid, time)` before the mutate.)

I'm inferring that what we need to do is replace all `NA` values with the first non-`NA` found in `index_date` within each group defined by `matchid` and `time`.

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(Study_ID = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 340L, 340L, 340L, 340L), time = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L), index_date = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA), case = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), matchid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH - This was exactly what I needed to do and solved my issues.

Answer (score 2):

`fill` should do:

```
library(tidyverse)
s = 'Study_ID  time index_date  case matchid

 1 101        0          2     1     1
 2 101        1          2     1     1
 3 101        2          2     1     1
 4 101        3          2     1     1
 5 340        0          NA    0     1
 6 340        1          NA    0     1
 7 340        2          NA    0     1
 8 340        3          NA    0     1'



t = read.table(text = s)

t %>%
    group_by(matchid) %>%
    fill(index_date, .direction = 'down')



# Study_ID  time index_date  case matchid
# <int> <int>      <int> <int>   <int>
# 1      101     0          2     1       1
# 2      101     1          2     1       1
# 3      101     2          2     1       1
# 4      101     3          2     1       1
# 5      340     0          2     0       1
# 6      340     1          2     0       1
# 7      340     2          2     0       1
# 8      340     3          2     0       1
```

Comment: I thought the same thing initially, and it works, though I suggest `.direction="updown"` to handle any order of rows (in case that's important, I didn't assume it from the OP).