# Copy values from one observation to another over several variables where NAs remain

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with NA values across several variables which I want to replace with values on those variables from other observations where they match on identifiers.

A simple working example would look like this, where the variables I want to match on are URN and OBS and A and B are the variables I want to fill where a value is available.

```
df <- data.frame(URN=c("123099","123099","123099","132089","132089","140876","140876","140876"),
                 OBS=c("1","1","2","3","3","6","6","6"),
                 A=c(3,NA,NA,1,NA,4,NA,4),
                 B=c(NA,4,4,NA,NA,NA,1,NA))
```

| URN | OBS | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123099 | 1 | 3 | NA |
| 123099 | 1 | NA | 4 |
| 123099 | 2 | NA | 4 |
| 132089 | 3 | 1 | NA |
| 132089 | 3 | NA | NA |
| 140876 | 4 | 4 | NA |
| 140876 | 4 | NA | 1 |
| 140876 | 4 | 4 | NA |

The DT approach from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998856/r-copy-value-based-on-match-in-another-column) works:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[!is.na(A)], A:= i.A, on = c("URN", "OBS")]
df[df[!is.na(B)], B:= i.B, on = c("URN", "OBS")]
df
```

However, this gets very cumbersome with my dataset as I have several variables that need recoding in this way. Is there a way to copy over values more succinctly than doing this for each of the variables that needs updating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::fill` with `.direction = "downup"` and `dplyr::group_by` here:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(OBS, URN) %>%
  fill(A:B, .direction = "downup")
```

Output:

```
  URN    OBS       A     B
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 123099 1         3     4
2 123099 1         3     4
3 123099 2        NA     4
4 132089 3         1    NA
5 132089 3         1    NA
6 140876 6         4     1
7 140876 6         4     1
8 140876 6         4     1
```